# Linux termios function data corruption while reading continuous 0xFF data

Tags: linux, serial-port, termios, data-corruption

I write one program for serial port ttyS4 which uses termios function.
That program is uses non-canonical mode.
I can able to send hex data and also able to read hex data.
my problem is when i am reading data which have multiple 0xFF byte received that time my serial port buffer filled addition 0xFF byte in garbage form. 
example
my transmit data is

```
01 23 73 00 03 7b 29 00 03 86 9c 00 03 61 73 00 00 03 5b 00 00 03 63 00 00 02 d6 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 70 00 00 03 e8 00 00 03 e8 00 00 03 e8 00 00 03 e8 00 00 02 2c ff ff ff fc 00 00 02 2c 00 00 72 89 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 93 00 00 72 9d 0b 35 33 0d 06 11 00 05 00 08 00 00 2a d9 00 00 28 22 00 16 00 01 00 05 00 ab 82 40 00 ab a9 50 01 01 01 00 00 00 1f 9b 71
```

but actual I receive data is as follows.

```
01 23 73 00 03 7b 29 00 03 86 9c 00 03 61 73 00 00 03 5b 00 00 03 63 00 00 02 d6 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 70 00 00 03 e8 00 00 03 e8 00 00 03 e8 00 00 03 e8 00 00 02 2c ff ff ff ff ff ff fc 00 00 02 2c 00 00 72 89 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 93 00 00 72 9d 0b 35 33 0d 06 11 00 05 00 08 00 00 2a d9 00 00 28 22 00 16 00 01 00 05 00 ab 82 40 00 ab a9 50 01 01 01 00 00 00 1f 9b 71
```

additional 3 0xFF (Garbage)received.
this problem is occurred when multiple byte `0xFF` received.

following configuration is made to configure port.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
fd = open("/dev/ttyS4",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY| O_SYNC);

struct termios SerialPortSettings;

cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600);  // 9600 baud rate

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;   // No Parity}

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; //Stop bits = 1 

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Clears the Mask*/

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;   /* Set the data bits = 8 */

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; //Turn off hardware based flow control

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;//Turn on the receiver of the serial port (CREAD)

SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;

SerialPortSettings.c_iflag |=  BRKINT;

SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~ISTRIP;

SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); //Turn off software based flow control (XON/XOFF).

SerialPortSettings.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG );//Setting the mode of operation,the default mode of operation of serial port in Linux is the Non - Cannonical mode

SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | ICRNL );

SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;

SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 100;

tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Please can any one suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself (i.e. the write and read code).  How have you verified that the transmitted data is correct?  Have you tried to read that data with a known-to-work program?  Your initialization code is broken.  The *termios* struct is not properly initialized; there is no call to **tcgetattr()**.

Comment: Your title grossly exaggerates the symptom.  The *"data corruption"* looks more like a mere duplication or repetition.  The *"continuous 0xFF data"* is only three characters turning into six characters.